# How are we accessing this 1D vector as a 2D one

Tags: c++, sorting

I was looking at the code for Bucket sort:

```
void bucketSort(float arr[], int n) 
{ 
    // 1) Create n empty buckets 
    vector<float> b[n]; 

    // 2) Put array elements in different buckets 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
    int bi = n*arr[i]; // Index in bucket 
    b[bi].push_back(arr[i]); 
    } 

    // 3) Sort individual buckets 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    sort(b[i].begin(), b[i].end()); 

    // 4) Concatenate all buckets into arr[] 
    int index = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++) 
        arr[index++] = b[i][j]; 
}
```

How does b[n] which is initialised as a 1D vector here:

```
vector<float> b[n];
```

get accessed as a 2D array over here in the concatenate function:

```
arr[index++] = b[i][j];
```

Comment: It's a 1D array of 1D vectors. Add them together and you get...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does b[n] which is initialised as a 1D vector here:
>
> ```
> vector<float> b[n];
> ```

This does not initialize a 1D vector.

Instead, it declares a 1D array of `vector<float>`s.

This means that `b[i][j]` is accessing the `i`-th element in the array of vectors, and then in that one is accessing its `j`-th element.

Answer (score 3):

`vector<float> b[n];` is not a 1D vector. It's an **array** of vectors. It's also a variable-length array and not valid C++ (it's a C extension provided by some compilers).

If you want a 2D vector of vectors the definition would be:

```
vector<vector<float>> b(n);
```

Note the type `vector<vector<float>>` and the parentheses instead of square brackets used to initialize the *size of the outer vector* when it's constructed.

Answer (score -2):

`vector<float> b[n];` creates an `std::array` of `std::vector<float>`, so it is an array of n vectors. This example might help:

```
std::vector<float> b[2];
float i = 1;
std::vector<float> first_vector = b[0];
first_vector.push_back(i);
```

Comment: It's a plain old array not a [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), that's a container from the standard library.

Comment: Correction: There is no `std::array` involved. `vector<float> b[n];` is an ordinary (but  non-Standard) Variable Length Array of `vector`s. A note: `std::vector<float> first_vector = b[0];` makes a copy of `b[0]` so  `first_vector.push_back(i);` does absolutely nothing to `b[0]` .